# hibernate - retrieving and saving date in mysql database in format I want

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, servlets

I am storing data in MySQL Database using hibernate in this way.

```
@Column(name="CREATION_DATE")
private Date creation_date;
```

I am entering the date in dd-mm-yyyy format using :

```
    String str_date = request.getParameter("document_date");
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = df.parse(str_date);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred in parsing date : "+e1);
    }
```

But when the date enters database it is in completely different format : for eg. if date entered is 22/2/2015 then date stored is 0022-01-03. And also I am unable to prevent time getting saved in the database, even though I have used TemporalType.DATE. Please help, because this has taken too much of my time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Mysql Docs :- [Date format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The
>   supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'

More over if you want to store time also in database,then define your `creation_date` variable like below.You will have to use `TIMESTAMP`.

```
@Column(name="CREATION_DATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date creation_date;
```

Comment: thank you but I dont want to store time, so I am use TemporalType.DATE, but thats not helping it still saves the time as 00:00:00:0

Comment: can you check your database schema, show create table <table-name>; what does it shows for the column?

Comment: can you alter it to simple date type instead of datetime type?

Comment: i dont know :P can I ??

Comment: ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname DATE;